# how to select max value and return many entries

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Suppose I have such a table :

```
theme    module  changed
0        1       1426070691
1        1       1426070300
0        1       1324014321
1        2       1241245585
1        1       1015421251
```

I need a SQL query that returns for the same theme and module the max value of changed:

```
theme    module  changed
0        1       1426070691
1        1       1426070300
1        2       1241245585
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL : Using GROUP BY and MAX on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045609/sql-using-group-by-and-max-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions provided on the duplicates referenced are both poor/incomplete. SO's got to get better at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to GROUP your results by `theme` and `module`:

```
SELECT theme, module, MAX(changed)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY theme, module
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join`

```
select 
t1.* from table_name t1
left join table_name t2 
on t1.theme = t2.theme 
and t1.module = t2.module
and t1.changed > t2.changed
where t2.theme is null
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: old school - i like it. Bit slow though

Comment: Why can't you just use `GROUP BY`?